# Docker error when running image in custom directory

Tags: docker

With default configuration everything is fine, but when I tried moving images elsewhere it was problematic.

I've tried using -g option targeting dir in my home and making symlink replacing /var/lib/docker to the same dir. Both didn't work.

When I run: docker run hello-world, image (this and any other) downloads from repository, but doesn't run - I get:
    Error response from daemon: error creating aufs mount to /home/trj/myproject/docker/storage/aufs/mnt/550dd5ebcead6c0b89dbd883089b1c3d8e8d1921cc8d41616bc35cc13e95f775-init: invalid argument

Deamon logs:

```
ERRO[1411] Couldn't run auplink before unmount: exit status 22 
ERRO[1411] Handler for POST /containers/create returned error: error creating aufs mount to /home/trj/myproject/docker/storage/aufs/mnt/28ae2c2c39254af36cbe4edc85ccb9123eec9f5619c51dc91a02193bd7841a4f-init: invalid argument 
ERRO[1411] HTTP Error                                    err=error creating aufs mount to /home/trj/myproject/docker/storage/aufs/mnt/28ae2c2c39254af36cbe4edc85ccb9123eec9f5619c51dc91a02193bd7841a4f-init: invalid argument statusCode=500
```

Docker version:

```
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Docker info (with symlink):

```
Containers: 1
Images: 2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 4
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-44-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.10
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.59 GiB
Name: trj-work
ID: ULL6:RCCE:OMPN:2O4R:6JFX:LKTI:DHEU:5VQQ:RUQP:WHQG:GNW6:BLJA
Http Proxy: http://localhost:3128
Https Proxy: http://localhost:3128
No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1
```

Can it have something to do with the fact, that my home dir is encrypted?
Did any of you had similar problem with docker?

Answer (score 0):

Docker usually runs with `root` privileges. But even the `root` user usually cannot access an encrypted home directory (unless he does some tricks described in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/397225/can-root-become-user-and-access-encrypted-home) on server fault like *sudoing* into your local user).

So a docker daemon running as `root` will not be able to access your encrypted home.

Comment: That is not the problem, when I'm logged in, home is decrypted and mounted so with root user I can access it - the image was downloaded, but couldn't run.